# Jsoup.connect() Получить документ полностью

Tags: java, html, парсер, dom, jsoup

Проблема в следующем: использую библиотеку Jsoup для парсинга HTML страниц, но загвоздка в том, что на некоторых страницах некоторые элементы генерируются js при загрузке страницы (на мой взгляд равносильно подключению к этой странице. Однако, когда я получаю *Document* путем `Jsoup.connect(url)`, я получаю все элементы, кроме тех, которые генерируются таким образом (в отличии от просмотра в браузере, например).
Вопрос: Есть ли возможность получить документ в таком же виде, в каком я вижу его в Google Chrome - F12 - Elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью JSOUP это невозможно. Так вы получите только статический контент, динамический не будет получен.

У вас 2 пути:

1. Изучить какой запрос отправляет сайт при подгрузке данных и отправлять его. Так вы получите данные, которые динамически сайтом подгружаются.
2. Используя `Selenium` эмулировать программно браузер и в нём, программно прокрутив страницу, получить динамически отображаемый HTML. Это сложный, долгий способ, но иногда только это и остаётся.

Comment: Спасибо! А есть какой нибудь способ сразу скопом выкачать весь контент по ссылкам, которые отправляются? может какие-нибудь другие библиотеки?

Comment: @МишаковАлександр, нет, готовых решений нет, т.к. нет типовых подходов для формирования API. Все всё делают по своему, засим надо вручную всё делать. Разбирать API и писать код, который будет его вызывать, парсить полученную инфы и куда-то складировать.

Comment: понял Вас, спасибо!